# package Metatrader in RStudio

Tags: r, metatrader5

I am trying to install a package Metatrader in RStudio. After the [command](https://www.metaquotes.net/ru/metatrader5/news/5153)

```
R CMD INSTALL --build MetaTrader
```

recieve:

Warning: invalid package 'MetaTrader'
Error: ERROR: No packages specified

How to install Metatrader in RStudio?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What's not clear? I ask: how to install Metatrared in RStudio, if varning falls out.